# ASP.NET Core MVC : model binding and complex types

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a model that has a property which is a class (complex type) which, in turn, has properties that are themselves complex types; turtles all the way down.

I feel that I ought to be able to do

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.MyComplexType" />
```

But apparently not so out-of-the-box.

Is there a simple solution? I really don't want to have to (can't be arsed) to write out an `<input type="hidden">` for every property.

Comment: The simple solution, is using simple classes, with no complex types. There are a ton of reasons why you should avoid sending copious amounts of data to the client, and if you're talking about a complex type that has many complex types, that's a good reason to implement view models. Send the bare minimum to the client, and do the mapping from the view model to the data model on the server.

Comment: The data is needed. If it wasn't then I wouldn't _need_ to be doing this. I think I'll just serialise it to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark your complex type's properties with the `HiddenInput` attribute:

```
public class ComplexType 
{
  [HiddenInput]
  public string Property {get;set;}
}
```

Then in your view call

```
@Html.EditorForModel(x => x.MyComplexType)
```

This will add all your properties as hidden.

Comment: What if `Property` is itself a complex type rather than just a `string`?

Comment: Apply the attribute to all your properties you want to bind.